# Cant change the background image of an element in Each function in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, each

I am quite new in Jquery and have a problem in changing background of an element in each function.

My Html code is as follow:

```
<div id="productsBox"><span id="productItem2181" class="productItem"> <img class="ProductImage" src="/media/1656/FootballShirts.png "></img> <span class="productName">
      Football Shirts
    </span> <span class="relavantSizeAdvice">
      2189
    </span> </span> <span id="productItem2199" class="productItem"> <img class="ProductImage" src="/media/1697/FootballShorts.png "></img> <span class="productName">
      Football Shorts
    </span> <span class="relavantSizeAdvice">
      2189
    </span> </span> </div>
```

I want to change the background image of class named 'productName' when its being clicked. My Jquery function is as below:

```
$('.productItem').bind('click', function () {
            var $tmp = $(this.innerHTML).each(function () {

            var className = $(this).attr('class') ;
            if (className == "productName") {

                    $(this).css("background", "url(../img/SmallGreenCheck.png) no-repeat");
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: `var $tmp = $(this.innerHTML)` looks *mighty* suspicious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery provides a variety of selectors for iterating through child elements. Here is the sample code that can solve your problem:

```
$('.productItem').bind('click', function(e) {
    $(this).children('.productName').css('background', "url(../img/SmallGreenCheck.png) no-repeat");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) and pass the source object as [context with selector](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) you do not need to use each here.

```
$('.productItem').bind('click', function () {
    $(".productName", this).css("background", "url(../img/SmallGreenCheck.png) no-repeat");
});
```

`Bind` is deprecated you would use `on` instead.

```
$('.productItem').on('click', function () {
    $(".productName", this).css("background", "url(../img/SmallGreenCheck.png) no-repeat");
});
```

If you have dynamic elements created then you can delegate the event to parent of your selector or document.

```
$('parentselector').on('click', '.productItem', function () {
    $(".productName", this).css("background", "url(../img/SmallGreenCheck.png) no-repeat");
});
```

Comment: Adil does of course mean `$('.productName', this)`. `this` used as the second argument creates the context that is mentioned, so you only selector *within* that context.

Comment: Yes, its converted to $(this).find(".productName")